# how to use actions-on-google dialogflow with restify in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, circular-dependency, restify

The `dialogflow` library seems to have support for `express` server and `firebase functions`.

I am using `restify`, and tried to link the generated `app` from actions-on-google SDK in several ways.

The closest I could get was: 
`server.post("/googleassistant", g_assistant.getApp);`
having the getApp making the proper app and triggering `next()` and returning the `app` or even using the `res(app)`

```
 Converting circular structure to JSON\n 
--> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'\n | property 'parser' 
-> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'\n 
--- property 'socket' closes the circle",
```

I tried using `const body_parser = require("body-parser");`
or the restify body parser: `server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());`
with and without mapping flag... but nothing

also tried to use it in the format `server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser(),app);` just before defining the POST for the webhook. Again the same circular JSON error on the response.

it seems that the request is coming in ok, I can read it, and I can also respond to the Intent with a custom object. But I would like to use the app from the dialogFlowSDK rather than parsing all the fields manually :(

Comment: Express and Lambda are supported through a [frameworks](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/tree/master/src/framework) system that allows an HTTP request to be properly routed. By taking a look at [Express](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/master/src/framework/express.ts) or other examples, you can build a parallel framework for Restify.

Comment: awesome, thanks! seems not many people bumped it to this so far, I will bear in mind when I revisit my project!